# Stretching an image to fill the height of its table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I have a table cell of unknown height which contains an `img`. This `img` has a fixed pixel width, but I need it to stretch to fill (but not exceed) the entire height of the table cell. The width should remain the same no  matter what the height.

Usually, I'd do this using `height: 100%`, but this doesn't appear to be working in this scenario:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Here is some content.<br/>
      I would like the adjacent image to stretch to be<br/>
      the same height as it, but not have the image get<br/>
      any wider.
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/20x20" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make the image fill the height of its cell?

Comment: If you added the height as an attribute on the image (not CSS) it would probably do what you want. `<img src="https://placehold.it/20x20" height="100%" width="25" />` But the CSS background answer below is more flexible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the image as background and you can easily achieve this. You can also keep the `background-image` as an inline style to be able to set it like an `img` element

```css
.img {
  width: 25px;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Here is some content.<br/>
      I would like the adjacent image to stretch to be<br/>
      the same height as it, but not have the image get<br/>
      any wider.
    </td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placehold.it/20x20)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In case you want to keep the use of `img` you can use `position:absolute`

```css
.img {
  width: 25px;
  position:relative;
}
.img img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Here is some content.<br/>
      I would like the adjacent image to stretch to be<br/>
      the same height as it, but not have the image get<br/>
      any wider.
    </td>
    <td class="img">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/20x20)"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a really clean way of doing this! Thank you.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen added another method

Comment: @TemaniAfif Email clients like outlook will not render it right. This is for HTML email not for web.

Answer (score 0):

With email clients such as Outlook desktop 2007-2019, you need to specify the width of the image, especially if you are displaying it in a size that does not match it's physical size. Otherwise Outlook will ignore your style sheet and revert to the actual size.

For the height, you can generally leave it blank and add in the style sheet `height: auto;`

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/20x20)" width="20" height="" alt="" border="0" style="height: auto;">
```

Good luck.